# MPI number of processors on Windows

Tags: c, windows, mpi

I tried to run the code below, but the result is always 1. So I'd like to know that is there a way to set the number of processors?

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int rank, size;

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);

    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);

    printf("number of processors:%d", size);

    MPI_Finalize();

    return 0;
}
```

The code runs on **visual studio 2017**.

Comment: I admittedly don't have an experience with using MPI in Visual Studio, but when using command line on Linux, the `mpic++` for compilation and `mpirun` for running the program were required parts to make it work. Try checking the build/run tools if you can specify these and their respective parameters. `mpirun` takes the number of processors in the `--n` or `-np` parameter.

Comment: Thank you so much@MartyCagas